# How to get the total amount in a database table field month wise of the current year using laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

So I have database with amount and created_at field on it and I want to the total amount per month of the current year and or every year.

```
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(amount) as "Amount",MONTHNAME(created_at) as "Month"
FROM transactions WHERE YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at),MONTH(created_at)';
DB::statement($sql);
```

Actual Table

```
ID    amount     created_at
1      1000      2019-10-24    
2      234       2019-11-11
3      122       2019-09-04
4      5200      2019-09-14
```

Expected Result

```
ID    Amount     Month
1      6322      September    
2      234       November
```

Syntax error or access violation: 1055 db.table.created_at isn't in Group by(SQL: SELECT SUM(amount) as "Total Amount", MONTHNAME(created_at) as " Month

Please what is it saying. However if run this query on phpmyadmin it works perfectly well

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

First set the `strict => false` in `app\config\database -> mysql`

after that run `php artisan optimize`

then

```
 $sql = DB::table('transactions')
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount) as Amount,MONTHNAME(created_at) as Month Name'))
        ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE())'))
        ->groupBy('created_at')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Give a sql syntax  Error the syntax to use near 'group by  `created_at`'

Comment: My fault seen it

Answer (score 1):

You're grouping on portions of `created_at`, then referring to `created_at` itself when you `SELECT`. The issue is that only aggregate functions and the things grouped on can be used when you group results in the query. If you use `MONTH(created_at)` in select instead of `MONTHNAME` you should be fine (or you could `group by YEAR, MONTHNAME` instead and continue to use `MONTHNAME` in your projection